# I am getting Aborted (core dumped) in below code

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

Hi in my below code for testing `realloc()` I am getting the error `Aborted (Core dumped)`.

**The output of the code is below**

```
$ ./realloc
My Name // <<-- This works
Aborted (core dumped) // <<-- why this error occur?
```

calling to `copyThis()` function 1st time gives the correct result and produce no error. In the same way if I call `copyThis()` for the second time, it make error. I can not understand why is it happening. Can any body point me out where the problem is and what the tweak should I do?

**The code is below**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *copyThis(char *str1, const char *str2, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr1 = "My Name ";
    char *ptr2 = "is Alice";
    char *ptr3;
    char *ptr4;

    ptr3 = copyThis(ptr3, ptr1, strlen(ptr1) + 1); // This works
    printf("%s\n", ptr3);

    ptr4 = copyThis(ptr4, ptr2, strlen(ptr2) +1); // this line make Aborted (core dumped)
    printf("%s\n", ptr4);
}

char *copyThis(char *str1, const char *str2, size_t size)
{
    str1 = (char *) realloc(str1, size);
    strncat(str1, str2, strlen(str2));
    str1[size] = '\0';
    return str1;
}
```

NOTE : Please point me any good tutorial site that can help me catch string operations well in c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str1[size] = '\0';
```

writes beyond the allocated memory, thus your program crashes. You should allocate one more for the `0` character.

The other error is that you call your function fro `char*` as first argument (`ptr3` and `ptr4`) that are not initialized. This has undefined behavior, anything can happen with such code.

A proper way would be to check if that argument is `0` and then just call `malloc` with the appropriate size. But for such an approach to work you would have to properly initialize these variables with `0`, which you should do, anyhow.

Also, don't cast the return of `malloc` and relatives, this might hide subtle bugs.

Comment: Sorry, It sould be `[size-1]`.  I modified it but still it makes the same error.

Comment: So do I need to initialize them with `malloc()` or `NULL` ? and regarding casting, if I dont cast, compilor gives a warning. how to deal with it?

Comment: @fSazy, if your compiler gives a warning there may be one of two things: (1) you don't include the correct header file for `malloc` (2) you are compiling C code with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 5):

The error is with:

```
char *ptr3;
char *ptr4;
```

You should initialize them to NULL:

```
char *ptr3 = NULL;
char *ptr4 = NULL;
```

Since `ptr3` and `ptr4` are not NULL, `realloc` assumes they were pointers to valid memory. From `man realloc`:

> Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call
>   to malloc(), calloc() or realloc().

Since those pointers are, instead, pointing to random addresses in memory, `realloc` will get confused when actually using them.

---

As a more general note, in cases like this it is very helpful to enable additional diagnostics when compiling your code. For example, if you use `gcc` and if you compile your code with `-Wall`, the following warnings are emitted:

```
file.c:19:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
file.c:14:10: warning: ‘ptr3’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
file.c:17:10: warning: ‘ptr4’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

How to enable those extra warnings depends on what IDE you use for developing, if any; otherwise, if you use the commandline, just add `-Wall` to the call to `gcc`.

Comment: you mean it should be `char *ptr3 = NULL` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do.

Comment: @fSazy Correct. I have clarified that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you have not initialized the pointers and when you are trying to use realloc it has garbage value and gdb shows :

Breakpoint 1, copyThis (**str1=0x7fffffffe060** "\001", str2=0x4007e4 "My Name", size=8) at prog1.c:22
22      str1 = (char *) realloc(str1,size);
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a95b54 in realloc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Due to the garbage address it was failing. So whenever you use pointers **always try to initialize them before using**.

So the correct program is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *copyThis(char *str1, const char *str2, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr1 = "My Name";
    char *ptr2 = "is Alice";
    char *ptr3 = NULL;
   char *ptr4 = NULL;
    ptr3 = copyThis(ptr3, ptr1, sizeof(ptr1) ); // This works
    printf("%s\n", ptr3);
    ptr4 = copyThis(ptr4, ptr2, sizeof(ptr2) ); // this also works
    printf("%s\n", ptr4);
}

char *copyThis(char *str1, const char *str2, size_t size)
{
    str1 = (char *) realloc(str1,size);
     strncat(str1, str2, strlen(str2));
    str1[size] = '\0';
    return str1;
}
```

Comment: The star symbols that you have used to highlight your changes break the syntax of the program ;)

Comment: I just used BOLD option which is given ..... :) but resulted in something else :D